# Windows 10 - stornvme driver detected controller driver when editing video

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, ssd, nvme

I have an LSI 9271-4i card, with 4 6TB WD Red drives in RAID 10, on Windows 10, that I use to store my Videos folder, where I save all of the video files that I work on and renders, etc. I will edit off of this array using Premiere Pro and DaVinci Resolve (although I don't think it's these applications causing any issues).

Most of the time this array is pretty stable, but lately I've been running into strange issues where Win10 will freeze, any audio playback that's happening will stutter quite a bit, and the the RAID drive will disappear completely from Windows (it comes back just fine if I reboot.) All of the firmware/drivers are completely up to date.

The Windows System log shows two of these Errors

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
> Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID

Followed by this Warning

> Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort0, was issued.

And then a ton of these Warnings

> The IO operation at logical block address 0x2d5a4ae00 for Disk 0 (PDO name: \Device\00000044) was retried.

Lastly one more Warning

> Disk 0 has been surprise removed.

A way that I can get this to happen every time without fail is to be rendering a video file from DaVinci Resolve, source on the drive, render output also on the same drive, and then I open Chrome that plays a YouTube video, and then it's gone.

I've already tried to follow the registry changes and power setting changes [here](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Reset-to-device-Device-RaidPort0-was-issued-Event-id-129/m-p/4657366/highlight/true#M861319), and I've also tried changing the format of my array from NTFS to exFAT, just to see, but the behavior remains unchanged.

Is there anything left to try to stop this "crashing"?

---

Update! So apparently this has absolutely nothing to do with my RAID card, and something else to do with my computer in general, since I seem to be able to kill my ability to interact with just about any drive plugged in; NVME in M.2 drives, USB 3 external drives, USB 3.1 Gen 2 USB C T5 SSDs, doesn't seem to matter at all. This happens consistently if I try to work with 6K video in Premiere Pro, where the drive becomes unusable but I still see everything on it, but if, for example, I run Crystal Diskmark on the drive after this happens, I get "Failed to create file".

Also the Windows system log shows

> Warning - sotrnvme - Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort2, was issued.
>
> Error - stornme - The driver detected a controller error on \Device\RaidPort2.

and then one of these errors every time I try to write to this drive

> Warning - Disk - An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk1\DR1 during a paging operation.

And the only way for me to come back from this is to reboot, but it happens in a few minutes once I start scrubbing through my 6K video again. This still happens if I scrub though/edit 4K video, but much, much more rarely

---

My hardware specs are as follows:

- i7-8700K (overclocked and stock clock don't affect the crashing)
- GIGABYTE Z370 AORUS Gaming 7
- Corsair CMW64GX4M4C3200C16 Vengeance RGB
  PRO 64GB (clocked down to 2666 to match the i7 listed max ram speed,
  also doesn't seem to matter though)
- EVGA GeForce GTX 1070 SC
- Seasonic PLATINUM-1000

Everything is up to date, Windows, Bios, all drivers, I've even reinstalled Windows and all the drivers multiple times, and all this is really making it difficult to actually edit anything. Running AIDA 64 full system stress tests shows no issues, I've swapped parts, like the memory, with totally different parts and still having issues.

Comment: You could try replacing the data cables.  It sounds like a hardware problem.

Comment: If it was hardware, why does it only crash immediately once I play video in Chrome? If I never open Chrome it never crashes, and the array is not the system drive

Comment: Hardware is funny.  For example you can have a GPU that runs perfectly find with a application that uses Vulcan, but will cause a system crash if DX12 is used.  If Chrome happens to be performing an instruction, that causes a problem, your error message could be explain by it.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to try some things then. Something else worth noting, the RAID card's log itself shows that it's been totally okay the entire time, no warnings (except about my not having the battery connected)

Comment: Another one, the Win task manager shows the drive at 100% while it's generating those second to last series of warnings

Comment: There might be other problems at play... I've had the RAID removed for a few days and installed another M.2 drive in the mean time and I'm having the same problems with it... sort of... It goes away but I can still see the files but I can't play them, and if I run a check disk on it, it says "CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.", but I can see it in the disk management tools as a healthy NTFS drive

Comment: This card new or old (when it was purchased)?

Comment: New, it's never had a problem. I think you're right, I think it's hardware, but I think I was looking too specific. This only started happening when I threw in some new 3200MHz ram, but my i7 8700k's max ram spec is 2666, so I underclocked it last night and so far no problems on any drives. I also lowered my CPU clock from 5.0 to 4.9. It was stable (at least up until a few days ago) but we'll see if I plug the RAID back in if it just works again

Comment: Added many updates to the post, doesn't seem to be raid at all, and more a problem with how my computer is communicating with any drive at all

Answer (score 1):

The problem may have been solved by a couple of power setting changes

First one was setting `Hard disk -> AHCI Link Power Management - HIPM/DIPM -> Setting` to `DIPM` (not `Active`, like I saw listed elsewhere)

And the second one was `PCI Express -> Link State Power Management -> Setting` to `Off`.

And after that (and a reboot) my method of playing a YouTube video in Chrome and scrubbing through the 6K video doesn't appear to make the drive disappear anymore. I also no longer see any errors/warnings in the event viewer related to my drives.

If the issue comes back I'll update this answer and/or the question again.

---

EDIT: This is till happening, albeit much less frequently, but it does occasionally still happen with the same errors & warnings I was getting before

Comment: I'm still not 100% confident that this is the real solution to my problem, while it appears to be working now, I'll definitely award the bounty to someone who has something definite to say regarding this issue